# php if i click the button program reload page and never continue execute the code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i press first button 'no' the page shows me another two buttons.

If I click the second 'no' button the page reloads from the beginning. How can i prevent it from reloading and continue to execute the code?

This is my code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" >
                   <br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" name="no" value="no" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <input type="submit" name="yes" value="yes"  > 
                   <br/><br/>                  
            <?php
               if(isset($_POST['no'])) 
               { ?>

          <input type="submit" name="no1" value="no" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="submit" name="yes1" value="yes"  > <?php
           if(isset($_POST['no1'])) 
               { 

               echo 'you click no1';
               }
                else if (isset($_POST['yes1'])) 
               {
                  echo 'you click yes1';
                }
               }

               else if (isset($_POST['yes'])) 
               {
                   echo 'you click yes';

               }    

               ?>

    <div class="clear"> </div></center>

      <center>
      </center></div></form>
```

Comment: use event.preventDefault()

Comment: You are using PHP where you should be using javascript, you probably want it to react immediatly when you click on the radio button. PHP is server-sided which processes code on the server and NOT on the clients browser.

Answer (score -1):

What should this script do ? If you could provide a few more information that might help understanding the issue.

Comment: it's a comment, not answer

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment on the question.

Comment: I cannot add a comment until i reach 50 rec's :(

Comment: program show me two buttons if i clicks first no button program show me another two buttons if i clicked second no button program print 'hi'
the problem in the second no button when i click it program reload the page from beginning .. i want it to continue code

Comment: @Danina, it's php. Using form you send request to the server, server responds you. That process work with page reload